# How do I change the colour of the texts surrounded by NavbarBrand tags

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

"I am new to ReactBootstrap....I tried giving its className and rendering using css that did not work"

```
                <Navbar dark>
                        <div className="container">
                            <NavbarBrand  href="/" >Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
                        </div>
                </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<NavbarBrand>` renders as `<div class='navbar-brand'... >` - so we just need to set the css for this class

relevant **css**:

```
.navbar.navbar-light a.navbar-brand {color:red;}
```

relevant **js**:

```
import './navbar.css';
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-navbartoggler-example-7wmceu)

Comment: Hi @H.U, as the questioner, you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answer... this way others can benefit knowing that it worked for you